# How did the author get to these inequalities?

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry, curves

[image]

Context: Here $\tau = \langle X, T \rangle $ and $v = \langle X, N \rangle$. I understood everything in the proof except for the blue part. Why is it that $\displaystyle{\lim_{x \to \infty} y'(x)} > 0$? Where do the final inequalities come from?

[This is the thesis where I got the text](https://dspace.mit.edu/handle/1721.1/83693). Page 25.

**Update:** I see why, if $\displaystyle \lim _{x \to \infty} \frac{y(x)}{x} = A$ for some constant $A$, and $\dfrac{y(x)}{x}$ is decreasing then $y(x) - Ax > 0 $, but I still do not see why $A$ has to be a constant (why cannot that limit blow up to infinity?) or why it is the case that$$
y(x) - Ax \leq x \int_x^\infty \frac{w(t)}{t^2} \,\mathrm{d}t \leq \alpha e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}?$$

**Edit:** Bounty added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\def\d{\mathrm{d}}$First, $w(x) > 0 \Rightarrow \dfrac{y(x)}{x} > y'(x)$ for all $x > 0$. For $x > 1$, because that $\dfrac{y(x)}{x}$ is decreasing, then $y'(x) < \dfrac{y(x)}{x} \leqslant y(1)$. Also, $y'(x)$ is increasing, so $A = \lim\limits_{x → +∞} y'(x)$ exists and is finite. Since $\lim\limits_{x → +∞} w(x) = 0$, then$$
\lim_{x → +∞} \frac{y(x)}{x} = \lim_{x → +∞} y'(x) + \lim_{x → +∞} \frac{w(x)}{x} = A + 0 = A.
$$

Next, because $\dfrac{y(x)}{x}$ is strictly decreasing and $\lim\limits_{x → +∞} \dfrac{y(x)}{x} = A$, then $\dfrac{y(x)}{x} > A \Rightarrow y(x) - Ax > 0$ for $x > 0$. Note that $\left( \dfrac{y(x)}{x} \right)' = -\dfrac{w(x)}{x^2}$, thus$$
\int_x^{+∞} \frac{w(t)}{t^2} \,\d t = -\left. \frac{y(t)}{t} \right|_x^{+∞} = \frac{y(x)}{x} - A.
$$
Also because $y'(x)$ is increasing and $\lim\limits_{x → +∞} y'(x) = A$, then $y'(x) \leqslant A$ for $x > 0$, Therefore,$$
x \int_x^{+∞} \frac{w(t)}{t^2} \,\d t = y(x) - Ax \leqslant y(x) - x y'(x) = w(x) \leqslant α\exp\left( -\frac{x^2}{2} \right).
$$

Answer (score 2):

It is written that $y$ is convex, so $y'$ is increasing,more over $y'(0)=0$. So $y'$ has a limit and this limit is $\geq 0$.

More over if this limit is $0$ then $y'(x)=0 \forall x$, so $y''=0$ which leads to $y(x)-xy'(x)=y(x)=0$. But $\alpha=y(0)>0$ so there is a contradiction.

Comment: Why does the convexity of $y$ imply in $y'$ being increasing? Also, couldn't it just increase forever and not have a limit?

Comment: If $y$ is convex and differentiable then $y''(x)=(y')'(x) \geq 0$. Indeed it could have $+ \infty$ as a limit

Comment: I see why $y'$ has to be increasing, but the other things are still unanswered, unfortunately. Thank you! The limit could indeed be $+  \infty$, so I don't see why the author treats it as a constant.